# Allegro 5 how to draw a scaled bitmap region

Tags: c++, allegro5

My allegro 5 game needs to draw a region of a tilesheet then i used `al_draw_bitmap_region`, but now i added the function to change the screen resolution, so now i also need to scale that bitmap but allegro 5 do not have something like al_draw_scaled_bitmap_region, it have `al_draw_bitmap_region and`al_draw_scaled_bitmap` but not both.
somebody can help me how use both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `al_draw_scaled_bitmap_region`, but there is
`al_draw_tinted_scaled_rotated_bitmap_region`. You can just pass 'default'
values to the parameters you don't need.

```
al_draw_tinted_scaled_rotated_bitmap_region(
   bitmap,
   sx, sy, sw, sh,      // source bitmap region
   al_map_rgb(1, 1, 1), // color, just use white if you don't want a tint
   cx, cy,              // center of rotation/scaling
   float dx, float dy,  // destination
   xscale, yscale,      // scale
   0, 0));              // angle and flags
```

You could also use transforms to scale your bitmap:

```
ALLEGRO_TRANSFORM trans, prevTrans;

// back up the current transform
al_copy_transform(&prevTrans, al_get_current_transform());

// scale using the new transform
al_identity_transform(&trans);
al_scale_transform(&trans, xscale, yscale);
al_use_transform(&trans);

al_draw_bitmap_region(*bitmap, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, 0));

// restore the old transform
al_use_transform(&prevTrans);
```

Comment: You could also draw your entire game to a normal offscreen buffer an then scale that single image at the end before presenting it to the screen